# Save a newly generated excel file in VB script

Tags: vbscript

My VB code generates a Excel file.
I need to save this excel file at specific location.
Can you please share how can I do that.

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="your_filename_here.xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```